# how to send selected text of an HTML page which is inside an aspx panel to the same aspx page but another panel?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, panel

I have an aspx page with 2 panels (C# code-behind), (Panel1 & Panel2). Inside Panel1 I load an HTML page. Inside Panel2 there is an aspx textbox. I want to select some text of the HTML page in Panel1 and send it to the textbox of Panel2. Would you please say how to do it?

Comment: Please post the code of what you have tried.

Comment: HTML Page inside Panel1 : I replaced text selection function with a simple form.

<body style="background-color:darkgray;">
    <form name="sending" method="POST" action="Display.aspx" >
        <font size="2">Name :</font><br>
        <input name="name" size="22">
        <br>
        <font size="2">Phone:</font><br>
        <input name="phone" size="14">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" name="Send">
    </form>
</body>

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayDocument();
            SelectText();
        }
 private void DisplayDocument()
        {
            String param;
            try
            {
                param = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(Request.QueryString["param"]));
                param=param.Remove(param.LastIndexOf("\""));
                param=param.Remove(0, 1);
            }
            catch { return; }
            FileDisplayPanel.Loader.LoadMask.ShowMask = false;
            FileDisplayPanel.Loader.Url=

Comment: [DirectMethod]
        public void SelectText()
        {
            txtAreaPaste.Text = Request.Form["name"];
        }

Answer (score 0):

If you know what part you want to select, assign it an **ID** and a **runat="server" value**, then you will be able to access it from the code.

For example:

If you have something like this in your HTML:

```
<div id="divForCode" runat="server"></div>
```

Then you can access the contents of the div in code-behind using

```
divForCode.InnerHTML;
```

and

```
divForCode.InnerText;
```

So all you would need to do is send it to the textbox (myTextBox.Text = divForCode.InnerHTML; or myTextBox.Text = divForCode.InnerHtml;)

Sorry I had to post this as an answer, I don't have enough reputation to comment.